# Bluetooth on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, bluetooth

What are the limitations of the Bluetooth on iOS? Can I program a Bluetooth in a way it makes the discovery procedure to find neighbor devices, selects a device from list, pair with it and starts over sockets exchanging some data (e.g. for peer2peer game? Is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

All hardware that can communicate with iOS devices using Bluetooh must comply with the MFI (made for iPhone) program. It requires the vendor to use certain kinds of hardware and require a device certification. The program is under a strict NDA.

It basically means that you can only make a connection between iOS devices or devices with the MFI label and not just connect to a another cellphone -unless your iOS device is Jailbroken of course.

Comment: Hi, the MFI applies only the PAN Bluetooth profile is used isn’t it? Most hands-free and handsets devices works and are not marked with „Works with iPhone” logo…
Can you please comment?

Comment: To my knowledge you can only Bluetooth connect to other devices that are MFi Compliant. This seems to be a limitation only posed on non-Apple apps(the iPhone can indeed use some headsets that are not MFi Compliment, but I doubt you could initiate the connection to them via the `ExternalAccessoryFramework`).

Answer (score 1):

yes it is possible. BTW only iOS devices are supported.

Take a look at GameKit framework in the documentation.

Comment: What do you mean? the iPhone can communicate only with iPhone devices? No 3rd party accessories are possbible?

Comment: If you want to connect to external accessories you need to use ExternalAccessoryFramework, but I never used it so I can tell you about limitations.
If you want to exchange data between iPhone/iPod/iPad you can use GameKit framework.

Comment: @STeN: A link to [iOS: Supported Bluetooth profiles](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3647). You won't find SPP listed there... And a lot of BT/external accessory stuff is under MFi NDA.