# Bluetooth HFP (1.5) communication on iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5, bluetooth

The Bluetooth v2.1 specifies the so called "Secure Simple Pairings" methods - one of those methods is called Out of band (OOB) and according to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth#Pairing.2FBonding) *This method uses an external means of communication, such as Near Field Communication (NFC) to exchange some information used in the pairing process.*

Whatever is the "external means of communication" of getting the PIN, the handsfree device id, etc. - is it possible on iPhone to initiate the hands-free connection from the code? I.e. if i have all necessary information in my application can I say iPhone to connect to the handsfree using given information?

If it is not part of the public API, has Apple some process to allow some companies to get access to some additional non-public features?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to connect a Bluetooth 2.1 device to your iOS device, you must do it through the Settings->General->Bluetooth screen.

However, for the iPhone4S and the New iPad, you can detect and connect Bluetooth devices that Low-Energy devices.

The Bluetooth Low-Energy specification is part of the (some-what) new Bluetooth 4.0 protocol and only these two Apple devices have the necessary components to connect with low energy devices.

Comment: Note that you can't do HFP (or any voice/audio profiles) over Bluetooth Low Energy, it is for low data applications.

Comment: Hi, I think it was possible to communicate using PAN profile with other devices even before iPhone4S and The New iPad - what is the difference there (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9681577/bluetooth-on-ios)? Must be low energy devices have Apple MFi certificate (https://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/)?

Comment: So there is not a possibility to initiate from the code the connection with handsfree?

Comment: No, not that I am aware.  There might be a way to do this with jail broken device or through some undocumented API call.  However, it is my understanding accessing undocumented APIs from within the Apple iOS software is against their terms of use.